# MYSQL PHP Foreach statement only submitting first insert into statement

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am trying to load an xml file into my MYSQL DB with a foreach statement. It is successfully looping through the XML file for some reason, but it seems like only the first time through the loop gets actually sent to the DB.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<chatcoderadmin>
  <!-- Table Alarcos -->
    <Alarcos>
        <Alarcos_ID>12</Alarcos_ID>
        <Device_ID>16cf10d0-5154-444e-96ad-46e913ac9761</Device_ID>
        <Sender>4849941474</Sender>
        <Receiver>2157389113</Receiver>
        <Message>Hi Connor</Message>
        <Service_Center></Service_Center>
        <SMSStatus>0</SMSStatus>
        <Timestamp>2015-09-10 14:09:45</Timestamp>
        <Replace_Bit_Set>0</Replace_Bit_Set>
        <Reply_Path_Exists>0</Reply_Path_Exists>
        <Is_Status_Report>0</Is_Status_Report>
    </Alarcos>
    <Alarcos>
        <Alarcos_ID>13</Alarcos_ID>
        <Device_ID>f0bd524e-2289-47b3-b9c6-65c6af2dce64</Device_ID>
        <Sender>4849941470</Sender>
        <Receiver>266781</Receiver>
        <Message>BstFreeMsg: Select privacy choices for new account or line(s). More info on how to opt in/out of Mobile Ads &amp; Reporting programs at boostmobile.com/privacy. </Message>
        <Service_Center></Service_Center>
        <SMSStatus>0</SMSStatus>
        <Timestamp>2015-09-10 11:30:01</Timestamp>
        <Replace_Bit_Set>0</Replace_Bit_Set>
        <Reply_Path_Exists>0</Reply_Path_Exists>
        <Is_Status_Report>0</Is_Status_Report>
    </Alarcos>
</chatcoderadmin>
```

This is the PHP code I'm using to process the XML

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

    $createAlarcos = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Alarcos_Data (alarcos_id, device_id, sender, receiver, message, alarcos_timestamp) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    $createAlarcos->bind_param("isssss",$alarcos_id, $device_id, $sender, $receiver, $message, $alarcos_timestamp);

    foreach($xml->children() as $Alarcos) { 

        $alarcos_id = $Alarcos->Alarcos_ID;
        $device_id = $Alarcos->Device_ID;
        $sender = $Alarcos->Sender;
        $receiver = $Alarcos->Receiver;
        $message = $Alarcos->Message;
        $alarcos_timestamp = $Alarcos->Timestamp;

        $createAlarcos->execute();

    } 

    $createAlarcos->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: This looks ok; I assume `$conn` is mysqli and not PDO? Any errors? Have you added debug to make sure you're actually processing more than one child from the XML?

Comment: $conn is mysqli. I am sure that it is processing more than one child. When I echo out the alarcos_id in the foreach and it gives both instances of it.

Comment: I've found that in some circumstances binding to variables that don't exist can cause trouble. I usually declare the variables as empty before binding them.

Comment: It didnt help to declare them as empty first.

Comment: Is it intentional that the parameters are bound before the loop?

Comment: @tyteen4a03 that's how you do it. Prepare and bind outside the loop, execute inside the loop. Personally I prefer PDO, no binding needed.

Comment: @miken32 Ah, dark MySQLi magic I take it.

Comment: aren't the ID's different? `<Alarcos_ID>12</Alarcos_ID>` vs `<Alarcos_ID>13</Alarcos_ID>`.

Comment: foreach($xml->Alarcos->children() as $Alarcos) {
You need to reference the children of Alarcos, not the children of xml.

Comment: @PeterDarmis question was edited afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the same ID in both XML elements. Probably `alarcos_id` is primary key in your database table so it won't overwrite. This is a good reason to check results for errors; `execute()` is probably returning false.

```
...
if (!$createAlarcos->execute()) {
    foreach ($createAlarcos->error_list as $err) {
        echo "Error $err[errno]: $err[error]<br/>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: The output of the execute query helped me find out that my primary key for my db table was not auto_incrememted. So it kept trying to submit my insert into with an id of '0'. THanks so much.